# Visual Studio 2019 | "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" NuGet Package | "Not available in this source"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, docker

### To reproduce this issue

1. Create an ASP.NET Core 2.2 web application (Angular, single page)
2. Right click on project and add docker support (linux container)
3. done -> the package manager now shows an "warning" inside the dependencies stating that "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" NuGet Package is not available in "this" source.

### What  I have tried so far

- Re-added docker support
- Restarted Visual Studio
- Restarted Docker
- Restarted my whole local machine

#### Expected Result

After adding docker support I have expected visual studio to download the latest versions of said azure container tools and automatically implement them so I could start docker simply by selecting "Docker" from the launch drop-down menu.

#### Actual Result

Visual studio didn't download the latest version of said NuGet package.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try installing Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" version v1.4.4 which is the latest target file to enable the visual studio tools for containers.

You can download it from here

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets/1.4.4

[image]

It worked for me with 1.4.4.

See if it helps.

Comment: I am actually working with version 1.4.9, which should in theory nevertheless work (since, at least I have thought so, it's a more up-to-date version). However, it seems like downgrading has solved my problem on at least that problem. Lastly, it seems like there are now some compiling errors, which there weren't before. As comparison, building & starting outside of docker does work... that's super frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio tries to restore packages in the project from the sources that are specifiedin Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager Settings.  In this case the package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets specified as a dependency wasn't available in any of the sources configured (possibly none). To resolve this, add nuget.org as a source with URL https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json (see instructions in Microsoft's documentation for [configuring package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources)). Then VS will be able to find and restore it.